# Using Content of an android button as a Google maps search term

Tags: android, google-maps

so, I am trying to create an app that searches for places to eat near my location, I have a number of buttons that I am wanting to use as search terms for Google maps.

However I have no idea how to call the text from the button as a search term.

This is the code I'm using to initialise Google Maps

```
    @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    //mMap = googleMap;

    // Search for restaurants nearby
    Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=ButtonText");
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
    mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
    startActivity(mapIntent);
}
```

Where `ButtonText` is where I would like the buttons text to go.

any help/advice with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Button class extends TextView class, you can obtain the button text simply by calling getText() on the button object.

```
Button b = //your button
String buttonText = b.getText().toString();
```

After that, form your Uri

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + buttonText);
```

**UPDATE**
To make a search when a button is clicked - create an OnClickListener

```
OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener({
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button b = (Button) v;
        String buttonText = b.getText().toString();
        Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + buttonText);
        ...
    }
});
```

and set it on each button

```
button.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: ok, as for implementing this for 6 or more different buttons would I have to implemnt this 6 different times once for each button or can i use a single function for all the buttons?

Comment: just create an OnClickListener and add it to each button, then use the button view passed in onClick to obtain the text and make the search

Comment: Great this worked perfectly, Thank you for explaining it!